# Extend/hook into where Magento decides if a product can be shown/sold

Tags: stock, extend

I have a problem i'd like to have some opinions on. I'm totally new with Magento, but not with programming.

Background:

I've built a small module to import stock quantites from a couple of our suppliers. It adds this to every product, mapped by supplier_sku and supplier_id. When a match occurs, product get supplier_qty. It still has its own "qty" which i from now own simply will call qty.

I'd like to have following logic (please note its pseudocode and i don't actually asks how the get a yellow icon)

```
//If we have it in stock, let's just sell it as usual
if (qty > 0) {

    //product is shown, can be bought
    //and on product detail "In stock (green icon)" is shown


} else { //here we don't have item in stock, so lets check if supplier has

    if (supplier_qty > 0) {
        //supplier has item in stock!
        //this product is shown everywhere, and can be bought
        //it still shows In stock, but now with a yellow icon.
    }

    if (supplier_qty < 1) {
        //supplier has not item in stock (and neither do we)
        //this time product is not shown anywhere, and can obviosuly not be bought
    }

    if (supplier_qty == null || supplier_id == null) {
        //at this point we actually do not know actual quantities at suppliers
        //or we might not even have a supplier attached to product
        //maybe this product should be sold? Idk, just want to make sure
        //this use case is taken in account
    }
}
```

There is some obvious ways to do it. One is, during/after import, set allow_backorder, is_in_stock and all that stuff based on logic above. It does feel dirty though. I don't believe that this is "single responsibility principle" to let some importer decide this.

I rather have SOMEWHERE to hook in when Magento decides what to show in category/search/etc and so on. I've tried to track isSalable() and isAvailable() down but litte to no success. This logic of course might be expensive performance wise, to I guess it has to be cached.

So. Questions
1) What is the best way to make sure this logic is followed (and stable)
2) Does isSalable() and isAvailable() used before caching?

Thanks in advance!
Christoffer

Answer (score 1):

To hide the add to cart button you could listen to the event `catalog_product_is_salable_after` and then do you logic there finally setting is_salable to false, but this would still show the products just make them unavailable to buy.

```
$salable = $observer->getData('salable');
// YOUR LOGIC GOES HERE AND IN CASES YOU WANT TO STOP PURCHASE DO THE FOLLOWING
$salable->setIsSalable(false);
```

As for caching this event will always be fired so as pointed out this could be expensive performance wise to do this check.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wasn't clear enough though.

Hiding the "Add to cart" is not a problem. The problem is where to put this kind of logic. I don't want to hack it on front end, but i would like magento to consider a product that has

qty > 0 OR supplier_qty > 0 as "in stock" whereas qty < 1 AND supplier_qty < 1 as "not in stock" automatically.

Comment: I.e, if i (through import, manually entered or by decrease after order doesn't matter) have products that match above criterias, it may or may not be able to see (in catalog, search, feed or whatever) or be bought.

When I choose "Display Out of Stock Products: no" in config, i would like Magento to hide products that are out of stock BOTH at own warehouse and at supplier. Products with qty < 1 should be shown as long as supplier_qty is present.